# Concatinating attributes in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, aggregate-functions, group-concat

I am trying to create an `aggregate function` that `concatenates` numbers by `grouping` them. How can I go about it? Let's say I have a table like this below.

```
Table Numbers
123
145
187
105
```

I want the outcome to look like

```
105_123_145_187
```

I know how to use `group_concat` separator `_` if I am working in MySQL.

How can I do it in PostgreSQL?

Comment: *always* include your PostgreSQL version in your questions. You've seen why; you were given an answer, but you're using a two-versions-old PostgreSQL that didn't have the feature, wasting everyone's time following up with a different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already such function:

```
SELECT string_agg(num::text,'_')
FROM Numbers;
```

Details here: [string_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html).

Tell me, if you use postgresql 8.4 or earlier version. I will show you, how to implement this function as custom aggregate.

UPD Custom aggregate:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.concat_delimited (text, text, text)
RETURNS text AS
$body$
  SELECT $1 || (CASE WHEN $1 = '' THEN '' ELSE $3 END) || $2;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'sql'
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;

CREATE AGGREGATE public.text_concat (text, text)
(
  SFUNC = public.concat_delimited,
  STYPE = text
);
```

Comment: @ignor im using the earlier version 9.0

Comment: mind if i ask what does the query  SELECT $1 || (CASE WHEN $1 = '' THEN '' ELSE $3 END) || $2; do.....is $1 a variable??

Comment: @theuserkaps `$1` is the firs parameter of the function. `$2` - second. You can name function parameters and use their names, or you can leave them without names and use `$1`, `$2`...

Comment: thanks the function works though it is not sorting the result is there anywhere in the code where i can add orderby??

Comment: @theuserkaps Try `concat_delimited(num::text,'_') OVER (ORDER BY num)`

Comment: i should run select concat_delimited(num::text,'_') OVER (ORDER BY num) from numbers

Comment: if i run this its returning 3 rows

Comment: i get something like 123 which is the first row,andd 123_434 in the second row then the other row is 123_434_567 i only want the last row

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21101/discussion-between-theuserkaps-and-igor-romanchenko)

Comment: It's much simpler to use `array_agg` with `array_to_string` FYI.

Answer (score 1):

For modern PostgreSQL use `string_agg(columnname,'_')`.

For old versions 8.4 and up, use `string_to_array(array_agg(columname), '_')`

See [the array functions and operators documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html).

Example:

```
regress=> SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(x::text), ', ') FROM generate_series(1,10) x;
        array_to_string
-------------------------------
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
(1 row)
```

*Always* include your PostgreSQL version in your questions.

Answer (score -3):

`concat_ws(sep text, str "any" [, str "any" [, ...] ])` is the function your looking for.

The first param is your separator, NULL args are ignored. See [The PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-string.html) for details.

I am not versed in pgSQL at all, but the answer for writing an aggregate function is going to lay there, check out [the pgSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql.html) for how to write your functions.

Comment: concat_ws() isn't an aggregate function.

Comment: ... and you'd be looking for `array_to_string` rather than `concat_ws` for this job anyway.